# Match anywhere except between double square brackets

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match a pattern except when the match appears in between double square brackets.

The pattern I'm trying to match is `\|`, i.e. the `|` character.

Example:

```
Val 1 | Val 2 | Val3
```

This will return 2 matches. However, I want to skip `|` char if it is inside `[[...]]`. Example:

```
Val 1 | [[ | ]] | Val 3
```

Here I do not want the | char inside [[ ]] to be returned.Therefore this should return 2 matches.

I tried negative lookhead but my regex doesn't seem to work.

I captured `[[ | ]]` using `\[\[.*\|.*\]\]`:

```
[^(\[\[.*\|.*\]\])]
(?!(\[\[.*\|.*\]\]))
```

Those don't seem to give me the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [SKIP-FAIL technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
\[\[.*?]](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\|
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQRVlS/1/)

**Details**

- `\[\[.*?]](*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - matches `[[`, then any 0+ chars, as few as possible, other than line break chars (add `/s` modifier to match across lines) and then `]]`, and then the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` (or `(*SKIP)(*F)` or `(*SKIP)(?!)`) will omit the match and will make the regex engine proceed to search for another `|` from the end of the current match
- `|` - or
- `\|` -  a literal `|` pipe symbol

Comment: Shouldn't it be \[\[.*?\]\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\| ?
\]\] would make it consistent I guess.

Comment: `]` is not a special regex metacharacter, it does not need escaping. The best practice is to only escape what must be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !